# Using @State Variable Properties as Bindings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm working through some exercises with SwiftUI and I've hit what I believe to be a bug, but I'm not sure.

I have the following code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var errorMessage: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .alert(
                isPresented: $errorMessage.isEmpty,
                content: {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Important message"),
                        message: Text("This is an important message"),
                        dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")
                    ))
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The issue is, the line `isPresented: $errorMessage.isEmpty` is throwing a compiler error stating

> Cannot assign to property: 'isEmpty' is a get-only property.

Is this the proper approach to doing this? According to Xcode, the `.isEmpty` property is of type `Binding<Bool>` which is what the `.alert()` function is expecting.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Yes, the .isEmpty property is of type Binding<Bool>, but `.alert` expects for isPresented read-write binding, so isEmpty does not fit here, what is reported by compiler. So yes, a bug, but not in SwiftUI. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.alert(
   isPresented: $errorMessage.isEmpty,
   content: {
   Alert(
      title: Text("Important message"),
      message: Text("This is an important message"),
      dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")
))
```

The parameter `isPresented` is an `inout` parameter. That means it's wanting to change the value to false once the alert is dismissed.

The only trouble is that you can't tell a String to do this: `"".isEmpty = false`

You will either need a new Binding value, or create an `if statement` like this:

```
@State var canIAlert = true
```

```
if $errorMessage.isEmpty {
   .alert(
      isPresented: canIAlert,
      content: {
      Alert(
         title: Text("Important message"),
         message: Text("This is an important message"),
         dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")
   ))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Binding` you pass in to `isPresented` needs to be mutable, since it is an `inout` parameter. The `isEmpty` property of `String` is read-only, so you can't use that as your `Binding`.

However, you can create a custom `Binding<Bool>` that wraps `errorMessage.isEmpty` like this:

```
let shouldShowAlert = Binding<Bool>(
    get: { !self.errorMessage.isEmpty },
    set: { if !$0 { self.errorMessage = "" } }
)
```

And then you simply need to pass this `shouldShowAlert` binding to `.alert`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var errorMessage: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        let shouldShowAlert = Binding<Bool>(
            get: { !self.errorMessage.isEmpty },
            set: { if !$0 { self.errorMessage = "" }
            }
        )

        return Text("Hello, World!")
            .alert(
                isPresented: shouldShowAlert,
                content: {
                    Alert(
                        title: Text("Important message"),
                        message: Text("This is an important message"),
                        dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")
                    ))
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `!self.errorMessage.isEmpty` in the `get` body, but this worked!

Comment: @marcshilling you're absolutely right, updated my answer.